# linter rule and null safety

Tags: dart, foreach, dart-null-safety, dart-analyzer

I recently replaced deprecated pedantic package with flutter_linter
and now I have hundreds warnings like this:

```
Avoid using `forEach` with a function literal.
```

it's related to [avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls.html)

it sounds good if you have non-nullable list, but what if code looks like this:

```
GetIt<SomeService>().someBehaviorSubject.value?.data?.list?.forEach((f) {
  //
});
```

How to change it? So it shouldn't be ugly after refactoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. I don't really have a great answer, but this is the best I can come up with, for now.

First solution is this which might not be the most efficient way to do it since we are properly creating a new list object:

```
void main() {
  final Map<String, Iterable<int>> map = {};

  for (final value in [...?map['test']]) {
    // Do something with value
  }
}
```

More efficient but also longer would be:

```
void main() {
  final Map<String, Iterable<int>> map = {};

  for (final value in map['test'] ?? const <int>[]) {
    // Do something with value
  }
}
```

The best solution might be adding an extension method on `Iterable<T>?` like this:

```
void main() {
  final Map<String, Iterable<int>> map = {};

  for (final value in map['test'].emptyIfNull) {
    // Do something with value
  }
}

extension EmptyIfNullIterableExtension<T> on Iterable<T>? {
  Iterable<T> get emptyIfNull => this ?? Iterable<T>.empty();
}
```

This is allowed since extension methods is resolved statically and by adding a method on a nullable type, we can actually make the call even on `null`.

But this does also means this solution does not work if the end result is `dynamic` since we cannot use extension methods on objects typed as `dynamic`. The reason is that extension methods are really not part of the class we extends, but instead static methods which the compiler automatically inserts calls to. The fix here is to add a typecast.

Comment: I wrote this extension in so many languages now, it's really useful, I don't know why it does not come up while the developers write the framework.